How can I allow div tags in CKEditor 5 in Craft CMS 5?
I'm trying to get used to CKEditor after using Redactor for so long in Craft.  I'm simply trying to allow the use of div tags in CKEditor.  I have found several conflicting instructions, none of which work.  Using the "Source" button in CKEditor I try to add a  tag, but it is always replaced with a  tag, or removed on save.
I see no way of reliably adding something like "AllowContent:true" since CKEditor is configured through /admin/settings/ckeditor.  And adding
"HTML.Allowed": "div[class],p,b,strong,i,em,a[href|title],ul,ol,li",
to my /config/htmlpurifier/Default.json has no effect.
On a related note... "Attr.EnableID": true has no effect either.
Thanks for any help!

Apparently, the HTML.Allowed does work in HTMLPurifier.  The effects don't show up until you create a new field in an entry, not on existing fields.  However, toggling the SourceEditing button is what is stripping the classes and replacing divs with p tags.  So is there a way to fix this problem?  It looks like General HTML Support would be useful (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html) but how do you enable that in Craft?

After a lot of digging, I came across this Issue for the CKEditor plugin which explains how to add htmlSupport configs.
https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/issues/217
Toggling the SoureEdit button now retains div tags and can be limited to a single class.
  "htmlSupport": {
    "allow": [
      {
        "attributes": true,
        "classes": [
          "alert"
        ],
        "styles": false
      }
    ]
  }

As @i-just points out, "name" isn't required.  It can be added, but only single tags are recognized (eg. "div").  Any regex is ignored.  This might be a bug in the CKEditor plugin not recognizing regular expressions in the config.  I have to assume that omitting the "name" HTML Support config will apply to all tags.
